# How to create new recursive json object from interface in Angular 8

Tags: json, angular, typescript, interface

I am trying to create a Json with the following format

```
{
  "via": [
    {
      "name": "Kittin",
      "vagon": [
        {"id":123},
        {"id":321}
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I use the following interface

**app.interface.ts**

```js
interface RootObject {
  via: Via[];
}

interface Via {
  name: string;
  vagon: Vagon[];
}

interface Vagon {
  id: number;
}
```

But trying to use it returns the following error

**app.component.ts**

```js
varData: IVias;

this.varData.via.push('foo');

// this.varData.via = 'foo';
```

> core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'via' of undefined

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Not an answer to your problem but the code you provided should not even compile. `varData: IVias;` should be `varData: Via;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the message says, `varData` is undefined.

Probably because it's not initialized at the beginning of your script.

A simple fix would be :

```
this.varData = { 
   via : [],
}
```